# Quando o SO considera o usuário um robô?

Tags: suporte

Ultimamente o StackOverflow (o Meta também) tem me mostrado bastante a página de reCAPTCHA ("Human verification") quando tento postar uma pergunta/resposta. Desabilitando o *preview* do markdown e removendo os botões de ajuda acima da caixa de texto

[image: Página de pergunta]

O que causa isso?

Comment: Como nós podemos saber que você não é um robô postando isso pra conseguir burlar a verificação do site?

Comment: @LINQ não podem, vão ter que confiar ou rejeitar

Comment: **Suponho:** Acredito que ocorra em 2 situações, **1)** o IP fornecido pelo meu provedor (da cidade, não é grande), não era somente o SOpt, mas muitos sites me obrigavam a usar o reCaptcha a todo momento, tenho quase certeza que CloudFlare (e serviços semelhantes) identificaram o "range" de IPs como suspeitos (que deviam ser mesmo). **2)** caso ocorreu quando me atrapalhei ao usar o site, não me recordo como foi, mas foi ao editar alguma postagem, creio que abri duas telas em sessões diferentes, e outra em outro PC. Outras vezes eu fui "deslogado" sozinho, pode ter sido coincidência.

Comment: @LINQ parece que temos um claro exemplo de um funcionário "espião" de [uma empresa 800% preocupada com o futuro da humanidade](https://pt.linkedin.com/company/skynet-oficial). Fiquemos de olho...

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Não sei se tem em algum lugar a fórmula utilizada ([aqui pode ajudar](https://meta.stackexchange.com/q/164899/140010), [outros indícios](https://meta.stackexchange.com/q/3346/140010), [mais indicando que se ver demais pode se *bug*](https://meta.stackexchange.com/q/81012/140010)), mas ela piorou recentemente e não poupa usuários com boa reputação ou moderadores, talvez por não confiarem no sistema de autorização ou temer por um ataque MITM, ou algo assim.

Pelo que percebo se você demorar muito para postar o que iniciou ou se colar um texto grande pode disparar o gatilho. Acredito que tenha alguma verificação de comportamento de como digita os dados e se for isso deve dar para olhar o fonte na página para obter mais detalhes. No mínimo ele precisaria mandar alguma informação de tempos em tempos para o servidor e isso poderia ser usado para tentar identificar um possível robô. Deve ter outras situações, precisa ser alguma coisa coisa fora do padrão, algo que leva a uma suspeita, o que eu sei é que é algo simplório, não é IA ou algo sofisticado.

Pode ser que o fato de cair alguma vezes nessa situação aumente a frequência.

Comment: Não tenho certeza agora, mas acho que o preview e os botões desaparecem desde que eu abro a página (de perguntar ou da pergunta que vou responder), se for o caso não deve ser algo que é disparado durante a formulação. Vou prestar mais atenção pra confirmar isso

Comment: Seria possível realizar um ataque ao site com um método MITM? Pensei que sites atuais já possuíam medidas e prevenções para este tipo de ataque(considerando o quão antigo o mesmo é) e portanto, não precisavam lidar com este problema.

Comment: Hoje é mais difícil porque tudo é criptografado, mas o MITM pode ser feito independente do site, o que difere é a facilidade que ele terá para obter algum resultado nesse ataque, esse é um do motivos que eu acho que o CAPTCHA deveria ser usado com mais parcimônia depois de só usar HTTPS, mas pode ser que alguém saiba de algum motivo que eu não sei.